Testing geometrical trend in a tail
I have a collection of values x1,x2,..., xm, ... xn, with n>>1. It has been observed that at 1<<m<n the points start following a geometric trend, i.e log(xi) -> linear. I need a method to find m. I need to remove the first m-1 values that exert disproportionate leverage on the regression of the tail.
PS. I am not an statistician, so I am sorry if my question seems like if I didn't do my research.

I guess that  your second inequality should read $1 \ll m \lt  n$.

You hint at two different objectives.  So: do you want to find the "change point" $m$ or do you want to perform the "regression of the tail" accurately?  These are not necessarily achieved with the same solution or even the same procedure.

To clarify, I was interested in finding the "change point", not fitting the tail accurately.

You can iterate through indexes from 1 to some value, remove the first i elements and check how well log(x[i:]) fits a linear trend. You can use simple linear regression and R^2 metric to evaluate how well it fits that linear trend.

This needs more details and analysis to be useful.  In particular, it needs a stopping criterion: how is this "some value" to be determined??

I did exactly this and seems to be working for the intended purpose. I chose "m" as the point at which (1-R^2) is minimum. Thank you!
